# Как правильно делать вложенные ячейки для таблицы с React MATERIAL-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Как реализовать подобную таблицу с использованием React MATERIAL-UI?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В `<TableCell/>` засунуть `<TableRow/>`, например.

```
<TableCell>
    <TableRow>
        <TableCell>1</TableCell>
        <TableCell>2</TableCell>
    <TableRow>
</TableCell>
```